# How to extract numbers from a dataframe with html tags in R?

Tags: html, r, regex, tags, data-cleaning

I need to clean my dataframe to take of the HTML tags from columns 2-4.

[image]

Does anyone knows a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
df$col <- gsub("<[^>]+>", "", df$col)
```

Or

```
df$col <- gsub("<.*?>","",df$col)
```

This uses regex to strip all html tags which usually enclosed in <>.

**Note**: using regex to strip HTML is not advised at all times however in your case it seems like your data set will have numbers which is why regex would be the best and simple option for you to go about it.

Comment: It worked in 95% of the cases, but I changed manually the other 5%.
Thank you very much!